# Degree of sum algebraic functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This question I have asked on mathoverflow already: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123921/degree-of-sum-algebraic-functions

Let $C$ - curve, $f_1, f_2 \in K(C)$. How to prove that deg$(f_1 + f_2) \le $deg$(f_1)$ + deg$(f_2)$ (or or where is it proved)?

Comment: Do the comments at MO not help you?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  Not yet (the best comment is advice to write there)

Answer (score 0):

As said, degree of $f \in K(C)$ is defined as $\text{deg}(f) :=\text{deg}( \text{div}_{\infty}(f))$ where $\text{div}_{\infty}(f)$ is the polar part of $\text{div}(f).$

Hint: If $f_1,f_2$ have poles at $a \in C$ of order $n,m$ respectively, what do they look like locally around $a?$

To be more precise, you should also argue what will happen if just one of them has a pole of order $n$ at $a.$

Comment: Do you know a reference for this result?  The result seems to be well known, but I couldn't find it in the first 15 books I checked.  I ask because I use the result in a paper I'm writing, and would prefer to give a reference than a proof.